# Remove extra commas from only 2nd and 3rd row of CSV file

Tags: linux, shell, csv, unix

I have a comma delimited file (CSV file) `test.csv` as shown below.

```
FHEAD,1,2,3,,,,,,
FDEP,2,3,,,,,,,,
FCLS,3,,,4-5,,,,,,,
FDETL,4,5,6,7,8,
FTAIL,5,67,,,,,,
```

I wanted to remove the empty columns only from 2nd and 3rd row of the file i.e. were ever the records starts with `FDEP` and `FCLS` only in those rows I wanted to remove the empty columns (,,).

after removing the empty columns the same file `test.csv` should look like

```
FHEAD,1,2,3,,,,,,
FDEP,2,3
FCLS,3,4-5
FDETL,4,5,6,7,8,
FTAIL,5,67,,,,,,
```

How can I do this in Unix???

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Wow, you're lazy. You didn't put in any effort; just "write this code for me!" and "any update?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using sed:

```
sed '/^F\(DEP\|CLS\),/ { s/,\{2,\}/,/g; s/,$// }'
```

We use a range of `/^F\(DEP\|CLS\),/`, i.e. the following command will only process lines matching `^F\(DEP\|CLS\),`. This regex matches beginning-of-string, followed by `F`, followed by either `DEP` or `CLS`, followed by `,`. In other words, we look for lines starting with `FDEP,` or `FCLS,`.

Having found such a line, we first substitute (`s` command) all runs (`g` flag, match as many times as possible) of 2 or more (`\{2,\}`) commas (`,`) in a row by a single `,`. This squeezes `,,,` down to a single `,`.

Second, we substitute `,` at end-of-string by nothing. This gets rid of any trailing comma.